# Error while using Primefaces 3.5 File Upload

Tags: jsf, file-upload, file-io, primefaces

In a project with PrimeFaces 3.3, file upload was functioning properly. I removed the Primefaces 3.3 and added 3.5. Since then, I can not function the file upload. Earlier I have added commons-io and commons.fileupload, I was not sure they are still needed, so that I keep these jar files as well.

Error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.primefaces.component.fileupload.FileUploadRenderer.decodeSimple(FileUploadRenderer.java:56)
    at org.primefaces.component.fileupload.FileUploadRenderer.decode(FileUploadRenderer.java:47)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.decode(UIComponentBase.java:836)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.decode(UIInput.java:771)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1228)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processDecodes(UIInput.java:676)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processDecodes(UIForm.java:225)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1223)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1223)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processDecodes(UIViewRoot.java:929)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase.execute(ApplyRequestValuesPhase.java:78)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:77)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Backing Bean

```
public void handleFileUpload1(FileUploadEvent event) { 
    System.out.println("uploading");
    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Succesful", event.getFile().getFileName() + " is uploaded.");  
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);  
    System.out.println("uploaf finished");
}
```

JSF page

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
        <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="maincss.css" />
    </h:head>
    <h:body>

        <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <p:fileUpload  fileUploadListener="#{staffController.handleFileUpload1}" mode="simple" value="#{staffController.file}"
                           allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/" />  
            <p:commandButton ajax="false" value="Submit" />

        </h:form>


    </h:body>
</html>
```

web.xml file

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter
    </filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>uploadDirectory</param-name>
        <param-value></param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Did you select a file? According to the source code, file is uploaded, but file name is null somehow. By the way, `allowTypes` works only on `mode="advanced"`, but that's not further related to the concrete problem.

Comment: Related: https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=3807 It says that it can occur when the upload element is present but marked disabled, some browsers seem to implicitly do that in some circumstances. Which browser are you using?

Comment: Same Result with both Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Yes. This error occurs after selecting a file and clicking the upload button in advanced mode with actionListner and also with using simple mode when clicking a separate non ajax button.

Comment: As the https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=3807 post suggested, I added  if(file == null || "".equals(file.getFileName())){
             return "";
         } Still the error was there. AS that link suggested, there is a bug and already fixed for Fixed for Elite 3.5.9 and 4.0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I also faced the same problem earlier when version changed from 3.3 to 3.5

but end up with 2nd solution given below finally

**1st Solution**

*There is some problem in primefaces advanced file upload*

I think `mode="simple"` is the problem in the `p:fileUpload` tag

Make `mode="advanced"` and test it once.

If it works ,fine then

The thing is you are giving mode="simple" and trying to handle in advanced way.

**2nd Solution** 
make your fileupload like below to handle in a simple manner

```
<p:fileUpload value="#{staffController.file}" mode="simple"/>  

    <p:commandButton value="Submit" ajax="false" actionListener="#{staffController.upload}"/>
```

And in your Backing Bean/Controller/staffController

create a property

```
    private UploadedFile file;

//getter setters
```

And put an *upload* method like below

```
public void upload() {
        System.out.println("uploading");
        if(file != null) {  
            FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Succesful", file.getFileName() + " is uploaded.");  
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);  
        }
        System.out.println("uploaf finished");
    }
```

Hope it helps

[Sources](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/upload/basic.xhtml)

**Hi Sorry for the late response.**

Please check whether you have added file upload filter for the servlet or not in your web.xml.

**1)**

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name><!-- your FacesServlet Name -->
</filter-mapping>
```

**2)**

Add commons-fileupload1.3.jar file in lib folder.

**3)**

Make sure your whether your form has the  enctype attribute or not

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">   <!-- enctype tag is important -->
```

Please check the abouve 3 points .

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried two methods. Initially advance mode with the fileUploadListner. Then simple mode with a separate non ajax button, and with the backing bean checking the null value. Still the same error. May be an issue with my libraries. I will give a feedback as soon as I solve it.

Comment: Still failing. Replaced 3.5 with 3.3, but the error persists.

Comment: Now works with Primefaces 4.0 and GlassFish 4.0 without any issue. Thanks

Comment: @BuddhikaAriyaratne What did you do to make it work with Primefaces 4 and GlassFish 4?

Comment: I removed fileUploadListner.

Answer (score 1):

The event that caused file upload error was not updating primefaces, but GlassFish update from 3.1 to 4.0. When I simply deploy the same application back in GlassFish 3.1, everything worked fine. Thanks